# Why does my Command.CanExecute always return false in unit test?

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, icommand

My Paste command seems to work during normal execution, but in unit test the `CanExecute` method always returns `false`.

**Code:**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public CommandBindingCollection CommandBindings { get; set; }
    public ICommand PasteCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        CommandBinding pasteBinding 
            = new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Paste, Paste, CanPasteExecute);
        RegisterCommandBinding(pasteBinding, typeof(ViewModel));
        PasteCommand = (RoutedUICommand)pasteBinding.Command;
    }

    private void CanPasteExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }
    private void Paste(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
    }
    private void RegisterCommandBinding(CommandBinding newCommandBinding, Type type)
    {
        if (CommandBindings == null)
            CommandBindings = new CommandBindingCollection();
        CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(type, newCommandBinding);
        CommandBindings.Add(newCommandBinding);
    }
}
```

**Unit test:**

```
[TestClass]
public class ViewModelTests
{
    private ViewModel _viewModel;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialise()
    {
        _viewModel = new ViewModel();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void PasteTest()
    {
        // canExecute is always false somehow
        bool canExecute = _viewModel.PasteCommand.CanExecute(null);
        Assert.AreEqual<bool>(true, canExecute);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint in `ViewModel.CanPasteExecute`? It might be a of importance whether it is not called at all or the value is ignored.

Comment: @Florian: Yes, the breakpoint doesn't get hit.

Comment: Should `RegisterCommandBinding(pasteBinding, typeof(LookupViewModel));` actually be `RegisterCommandBinding(pasteBinding, typeof(ViewModel));`?

Comment: @Florian: Another typo! My apologies. See how heavily I rely on the compiler to counter my carelessness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you bind your `CommandBindings` property to a UI control at some point, and that the command is fired from the UI?

`RoutedCommands` like `ApplicationCommands.Paste` rely on there being a `CommandBinding` at a parent UI element, above that which the command is fired on.  The command's `CanExucute` request starts at the control on which the command is invoked (either the current focus or the command's target), and bubbles upward like a `RoutedEvent` looking for a matching `CommandBinding`.  When it finds one, it executes the `CanExecute` delegate from the binding to return the value you're looking for.

Because there's no UI in your test, and no target for the command, calling the command's `CanExecute` will simply not find a delegate and will thus return false.

So, I don't think your test in its current form would work without the UI being present.

(I'm going to go test my theory now - will edit later!)

Comment: Thanks, I look forward to it.

Comment: Hi Phil - looks like I am correct, from my testing.  Do you bind something in your UI to the `CommandBindings` property of your view?

Comment: Yes, I do. I've exposed public methods on my ViewModel that do the work and I'm calling those in my unit tests. It seems a bit dirty, but it's better than no unit testing.

Comment: Just wondering if you ever found a better way for testing these types of methods that doesn't break encapsulation @PhilGan

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I've found that this is still a problem.

After reading Dan Puzey's answer, and searching down-down-down into what CanExecute needs to run properly, I adapted my unit tests to add a dummy UI Element to attach to:

```
var aButton = new Button();
aButton.CommandBindings.Add(command);
            
Assert.That((command.Command as RoutedUICommand).CanExecute(null, 
aButton), Is.EqualTo(canExecute));

if (canExecute)
{
    (command.Command as RoutedUICommand).Execute(null, aButton);
    //verify Execute results
}
```

This keeps encapsulation, while allowing the results of both CanExecute and Execute to be checked. Note that, as far as I can tell, a call to Execute still also calls CanExecute, so you can't check the results of just Execute without forcing CanExecute to return true in some way.

It doesn't have to be a button, any UI Element that can bind a command will do.