# How can I test a RoutedUICommand?

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, testing, routed-commands

I have an application that I am building unit tests for.  For certain operations, I use `ApplicationCommands` (eg. `ApplicationCommands.New`).  Is there an easy way to call `CanExecute` and `Execute` on a routed UI command in the unit test?  I thought about implementing a mock `IInputElement`, but that seems like a lot of work.  Is there a better way?

```
[TestMethod]
public void NewDocument()
{
     Assert.IsTrue(ApplicationCommands.New.CanExecute(null, mockTarget));
     ApplicationCommands.New.Execute(null, mockTarget);
     Assert.IsTrue(workspace.OpenDocuments.Count == 1);
}
```

It looks like this is very similar to this question [why-does-my-command-canexecute-always-return-false-in-unit-test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511327/why-does-my-command-canexecute-always-return-false-in-unit-test) Does anyone know of a way to execute the routed ui command without the ui actually being there?

I have the command and command binding, but I don't know how to create the command source and command target.

Answer (score 0):

You should be testing the actual `ICommand` class that responds to the routed command.  If this routed command is implemented just by event handlers in one of you code-behind files, then I'd suggest pulling an `ICommand` out of those and testing that.

Testing that the command is routed properly is not a unit test you should be writing.  Instead that should be an integration test that could be done with [coded UI testing via Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx) (or some other GUI test framework).

Comment: I don't actually have a command in my view model.  I have a `CommandBinding` and a `CommandBindingCollection`.  The collection is what I use in the xaml.  If I try to test the `ICommand` object out of the routed UI command binding, `CanExecute` is always false.

Comment: That's what I was getting at with my second sentence.  Your code isn't very unit-testable set up how you have it.  In order for the routed command to work, your entire view needs to be created and run in a WPF environment since that is what hooks up the command to the binding.  If you pull out the `CanExecute`/`Execute` handlers into a command object, it's much easier to test.